# MySQL speed up subquery with sum

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I need a query for getting an overview of the actual stock (only one row for every unique product ID) and all the sales- and purchase orders. Right now, we make use of two subqueries (sales- and purchase orders) because there could be multiple sales- and purchase orders.
This query is extremely slow because of the two subqueries. Is there an alternative way to get the sum of the sales orders and the sum of the purchase orders with for example a regular left join?

Current query

```
SELECT stock.quanity, salesOrders.quantity, purchaseOrders.quantity
FROM stock
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity
   FROM sales_orders
   GROUP BY product_id
) salesOrders ON stock.product_id=salesOrders.product_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity
   FROM purcahse_orders
   GROUP BY product_id
) purchaseOrders ON stock.product_id=purchaseOrders.product_id
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on `stock.product_ID` and `salesOrders.product_ID` and `purchaseOrders.Product_ID`?

Comment: Yes, the product is columns have indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that correlated subqueries will be faster, with the right indexing:

```
SELECT s.quantity, 
       (SELECT sum(so.quantity) FROM sales_orders so WHERE s.product_id = so.product_id
       ) as sales_quantity ,
       (SELECT sum(po.quantity) FROM purchase_orders po WHERE s.product_id = po.product_id
       ) as purchase_quantity 
FROM stock s ;
```

For this to have any hope of improving performance, you need indexes on `sales_orders(product_id, quantity)` and `purchase_orders(product_id, quantity)`.

Comment: That should be a good idea, but the there is one problem: there should be a having statement: po.quantity+stock.quantity < so.quantity.

Comment: Wow I always thought these types of queries would be slower as each select would be run once per record in stock.  If stock had 1000 records you'd be running 2001 queries vs a join which runs 3 queries.  I never realized the join overhead would be so much.  I could see it be more efficient if stock had only a few records or stock were a subset of the whole; but if stock is 100's of records... I guess I need to test!

Comment: @xQbert . . . In MySQL, aggregations using correlated subqueries can be faster than using `join`s, assuming you have the right indexes.  The explanation is too long for the comment box.

Comment: @Stefan . . . That is not part of your question, but you can add the `having` clause.

Comment: This solutions is awesome! I did speed up the query from 10 sec to just 1 sec! Thanks a lot!
Just one small question: is it possible to add po.quantity+stock.quantity-so.quantity in the field list?

Comment: @Stefan . . . You would need to use a subquery.  Repeating the expressions would probably double the time of the query.